# mysql 8 could not login after install centos 7

Tags: mysql

I followed [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html) to install mysql 8. However, could not login with root account. I tried these methods:

`mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking` error: no mysqld_safe

`mysqld --initialize-insecure` error: --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it

One last thing I could try is to reset password for root like one has forgotten, just cannot accept this for it makes no sense.

Comment: The link says it sets root password in /var/log/mysqld.log, and you can reveal it with sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log . Have you check that out?

Comment: @tomyforever thanks! :/

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ensure that MySQL is installed successfully, and it will automatically generate password：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kky4x.png)

[image]